# What should be the i18n key for the default english version?

Tags: internationalization, translation

I started implementing internationalization in my code, but I am not sure how to name the default key.

I have seen a lot of different "sublanguages"-keys like **en_US** or **en_GB** but what should be the default when you add the first english version to your code? **en_US**?

Comment: If I understand you correctly: just **en**?

Comment: hm, that sounds too easy now =D. But you could be right - I found it in some lists as "general english"

Comment: Due it was a general question, I implement it now like you suggested =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default key for english is **en**.

When the user has the language set as `en_US` or `en_GB` it will take the default `en`.